# Prove $e^{T^{-1}AT} = T^{-1}e^AT$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $T$ be a $n \times n$ invertible matrix, A $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that $e^{T^{-1}AT} = T^{-1}e^AT$. Also, if we know $T^{-1}AT$ and $T$, how can we calculate the matrix exponential $e^{At}$.

For now, I don't know where to start so I would really appreciate some hints, thank you!

Comment: My hint would be to write down the definition of the exponential.

Comment: Observe that $\exp(A)$ for a square matrix is defined via series. Furthermore, you have $(T^{-1}AT)^k=T^{-1}A^k T$.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I have figured out the first question. How about the second one?

Comment: If you know $T^{-1}AT$ and $T$ you can easily find $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: first prove by induction $(T^{-1}AT)^n=T^{-1}A^nT$, then use $e^M=\sum_{n\ge0}\tfrac{M^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I have figured out the first question. How about the second one?

Comment: @sucksatmath Compute $e^X$ by choosing $T$ for which $X=T^{-1}AT$ with $A:=TXT^{-1}$ diagonal. Then $e^X$ is computed by the obvious transformation of the leading diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n \times n $ matrix $A$, $e^A=I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{A^n}{n!}+\cdots$. From this it can be easily shown that $e^{T^{-1}AT}=T^{-1}e^A T$.